# STORAGE_ERROR on assignment to array element

Tags: arrays, memory-management, ada

I have this array type:

```
type Rowid_X_Mv is array (Metadata_Version range Mv_1_0 .. Mv_2_3) of Integer;
```

where `Metadata_Version` is defined as:

```
   type Metadata_Version is (Mv_1_0, Mv_1_1, Mv_1_2, Mv_2_1, Mv_2_2, Mv_2_3);
   for Metadata_Version use
     (Mv_1_0 => 1,
      Mv_1_1 => 2,
      Mv_1_2 => 3,
      Mv_2_1 => 4,
      Mv_2_2 => 5,
      Mv_2_3 => 6);
```

I can create instances of this array, and I can access individual elements, but assignment doesn't work.  Why?

```
   function Rowids_For_Chosen (Db : Gnade.Database; Chosen : Integer) return Rowid_X_Mv is
      use Gnade;
      Result : Rowid_X_Mv      := (others => -1);
      Raw    : constant String := "select ... where rowid = ?";
      Stmt   : Gnade.Statement;
   begin
      Cd.Prepare (Db, Raw, Stmt);
      Gnade.Bind_Int (Stmt, 1, Interfaces.C.int (Chosen));
      if Cd.Fetch (Db, Stmt) then
         if Gnade.Column_Type (Stmt, 0) /= Gnade.Sqlite_Null then
            Ati.Put_Line ("found base id " & Integer'Image (Gnade.Column_Int (Stmt, 0)));
            Ati.Put_Line ("result " & Result'Image);
            Ati.Put_Line ("result v1.0: " & Result (Mv_1_0)'Image);
            -- This line raises the storage exception
            Result (Mv_1_0) := Gnade.Column_Int (Stmt, 0);
            -- ...
```

On a side note, if there's a better way to have named constants that behave like a range of numeric values, and it also addresses my problem, that'd be great.  Esp. since in other places I need to figure out next / previous versions and the way I currently have it is asking for a better solution.

---

Update: This appears to be independent of compiler version, whether `Metadata_Version` type defines a "non-standard" representation or not. It doesn't matter what index is used (i.e. `Mv_1_1` is just as bad as `Mv_1_0`).  Assignment also fails if the index is `Result'First`).

---

Update 2: Sorry for the trouble.  This turned out a memory corruption that sipped in through C bindings to SQLite.  Essentially, a use after free.  It just affected Ada code in a bad way that made it look like the error is coming from it.

Comment: what type is Gnade.Column_Int( Stmt, 0)?

Comment: Enumeration types are not named numeric string constants. They do not behave like numeric values. Enumeration types have no arithmetic operators. Ada allows you to index arrays using any discrete type. Enumerations are discrete types.

Comment: `Gnade.Column_Int( Stmt, 0)` is `Integer`, but this isn't essential. You can replace this code with assigning a literal 42 or w/e other integer value you want. I used "named constants" to describe the purpose of why I need this type. I.e. "named constant" is a name in the program that is always associated to some value, to contrast with unnamed constant, which is just a literal value, like 'x' or -3.14 etc.

Comment: `> Ada allows you to index arrays using any discrete type. Enumerations are discrete types.` Then why doesn't it work?

Comment: `Metadata_Version range Mv_1_0 .. Mv_2_3` is the same as `Metadata_Version`. Your problem may be related to Metadata_Version having a non-standard representation, or a compiler error dealing with an array indexed by such an enumeration type. Note that you can say `type Metadata_Version is range 1 .. 6;` and then define constants such as `Mv_1_0 : constant Metadata_Version := 1;`.

Comment: Why do you need the enumerations to have a specific value representation? Indexing using enumerations works without specifying underlying values. You still have names for each index of the array. In Ada you cannot substitute the value 1 for Mv_1_0 when indexing the array.

Comment: I tried a small compilable example and did not get the storage error.  What version of GNAT are you running to compile it?

Comment: "doesn’t work". It’d be great it you gave us a [mcve].

Comment: `Why do you need the enumerations to have a specific value representation?` Because I want to do things like increment / decrement version, tell which one is greater, store it in a database and read it back. But there could be a different way to accomplish this. Anyways. I want to understand the problem I'm facing, the reason I cam up with it is not important.

Comment: `What version of GNAT are you running to compile it?` I've tried version 12.2.1 and 13.2.1 -- both produce the same result.

Comment: `It’d be great it you gave us` is this another way of saying that this should work, and if it doesn't then it's not my fault? (I.e. compiler / linker problem etc.) I'm sorry, there won't be a minimal reproducible example if that's the case. Because it just means that it doesn't work in this specific situation.

Comment: `Your problem may be related to Metadata_Version having a non-standard representation`. I tried removing the "non-standard" representation -- this doesn't affect the outcome.

Comment: @wvxvw Normal enumerations allow you to compare which is greater, which is next or previous and may be stored in a database as a string and then converted back to an enumeration value after being read from the database. Ada enumerations are not named numbers.